# How to handle a Git discontinuity?

Tags: git

Let's say that in our Git repository, we worked on branch `master` for a while. Then, most of us started working on `coolfeature` branch, while a few developers continued on `master`.

Now, the developers who worked on `master` have lost interest, and what they developed since we forked isn't very important. But we'd like the main development branch to be called `master` again. Conceptually, we'd basically like the tree to look something like this:

```
*--master--X      ----master
 \               /
  --coolfeature--
```

What's the easiest way to achieve this? We really don't want to try and merge coolfeature, and we're happy for the commit marked X to be totally meaningless.

Comment: To effectively manage features in this manner, it would be wise to use a workflow that allows this. Branch per feature is what you should be looking at. Google "Branch-per-feature" and you should land on an in-depth article about how to go about managing a workflow like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a force push with the new master branch.

```
git push -f origin master
```

Other people fetch the code, and perform a reset

```
git fetch origin master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: And how to rename 'coolfeature' as 'master'? 'git branch -d master; git branch -m coolfeature master'?

Comment: It is "renamed" by the `push` operation: the commit pointed to by the branch "master" in the origin repository is set to be the one in the HEAD of the repo where the `push` is done.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do this and avoid doing a forced push:

1. create a tag for the commit X that you don't care about. (You'll see why in a minute.
2. Perform a `git revert` of all the commits on the master branch since you branched off coolfeature. This puts the repository back to the state it was at the time you forked, but it doesn't rewrite history, so nobody's repository gets broken if they didn't get the memo.
3. Merge coolfeature onto master.

The point about tagging X is to mark the point before you did all the changes. Tags are cheap, and at some point you might want to know the point at which you backed out commits and made such a change.